# DNS issue after upgrading to 22.10

Tags: networking, dns, 22.10

I just upgraded to 22.10 and my WiFi isn't working.
I am connected to the network but when I try to ping 'google.com' I get a 'Temporary failure in name resolution'.

My /etc/resolv.conf exists and contains

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

I can't even ping 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4 directly.

netplan config :

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

`ip r`:

```
default via 130.190.51.254 dev wlp2s0 proto dhcp src 138.190.50.200 metric 600
130.190.48.0/22 dev wlp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 138.190.50.200 metric 600

169.254.0.0/16 dev br-c7161284c546 scope link metric 1000
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-5571791d182b proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1 linkdown 
172.19.0.0/16 dev br-c7161284c546 proto kernel scope link src 172.19.0.1
```

What should I do ?

Comment: Attach netplan configs, located in `/etc/netplan/`, to your question. You may add `ip r ` too.