# After upgrade from 22.04 to 22.10, DNS does’t work anymore

Tags: networking, upgrade, dns

## What I tried

```
sudo service NetworkManager status
```

NetworkManager is active running.

```
sudo service systemd-resolved start
```

Got error:

Failed to restart systemd-resolved.service: Unit systemd-resolved.service not found

My `/etc/resolv.conf` doesn’t  exits。

```
sudo ln /usr/bin/resolvectl /usr/bin/systemd-resolv
```

Not working because `/usr/bin/resolvectl` not exists

Then I reinstalled `systemd`

```
sudo apt reinstall systemd
```

Unfortunately everything is still the same as above.

## Related issues

No one works for my case.

[DNS issue after upgrading to 22.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1436536/dns-issue-after-upgrading-to-22-10)

[Upgraded to 22.04.01, DNS didn't work, tried to fix, now Ethernet doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1432153/upgraded-to-22-04-01-dns-didnt-work-tried-to-fix-now-ethernet-doesnt-work?rq=1)

Comment: "My /etc/resolve.conf doesn’t exits" I believe it is `/etc/resolv.conf` Let's take a look at: `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555, thanks, it is a typo, fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the systemd-resolved is not included in systemd in Ubuntu 20.10, after upgrading, I installed it manually,

```
sudo apt install systemd-resolved
```

Now everything works.